# form_form and custom parameter in path_prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, form-for

I have this route:

```
# config/routes.rb
map.namespace :backshop, :path_prefix => '/:shop_id/admin' do |backshop|
  backshop.resources  :items
end
```

And I want to use the **form_for** magic to reuse the same form on both: **new** and **edit** views:

```
<% form_for [:backshop, @item] do |f| %>
```

This used to works, and used to build a **create url for the item** or **update url for the item** depending on the status of the **@item** object.

But this is not working on this case because the routes don't exists without the **shop_id** parameter, and I don't know how to say to the **form_for** something like this:

```
<% form_for [:backshop, @item], :shop_id => @shop do |f| %>
```

Because it tries to use the **@item** like the **:shop_id** parameter.

Or like this

```
<% form_for [:backshop, @shop, @item] do |f| %>
```

Because it tries to build this url:

```
backshop_shop_order_path
```

I Know I can just to extract the **form_for** declaration from the partial and do different calls on depending if **new** or **edit**:

```
<% form_for( @item, :url => backshop_items_path( @shop ) ) do |f| %>
```

and

```
<% form_for( @item, :url => backshop_item_path( @shop, @item ) ) do |f| %>
```

But I just wanted don't do this because I have a bunch of models and is a few boring :)

Thanks for any suggestion

f.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to do nested resources with a namespace maybe you can rewrite your routes to something like

```
map.namespace(:admin) do |admin|
  admin.resources :shops do |admin_shop|
     admin_shop.resources :item
  end
end
```

Now you should be able to use `[@shop, @item]` to get the route you want.  Use `rake routes` to examine the routes and see if they are to your liking.

Comment: Thanks Corey, this is very helpful.